# Problemas con 2 arrays

Tags: javascript

actualmente tengo el siguiente código:

```
articulo.prototype.crearEspecificAsoc = function ($table) {
    var lista = this.getColumnasEspec();
    //this.View.initTablaEspecificacion($table, this.lstEspecificacionesView, lista); 
    this.View.initTablaEspecificacion($table, this.lstEspecificacionesAsociadas, lista); 
    console.log(lista, ' lista');

    var lista2 = this.lstEspecificacionesAsociadas;

    var lista3 = lista2.sort();
    lista2[4] = lista.field;



    console.log(this.lstEspecificacionesAsociadas, 'this.lstEspecificacionesAsociadas');
    console.log(lista2, ' lista2');

    return true;
};

articulo.prototype.getColumnasEspec = function () {
    var arr = [];
    var objColumns = {};

    objColumns['field'] = 'IdNew';
    objColumns['title'] = 'Id';
    arr.push(objColumns);

    _.forEach(this.lstEspecificaciones, function (item, index) {

        objColumns = {};

            objColumns['field'] = item.Nombre;//'Valor';//Valor[i]/*.Valor*/;
            objColumns['title'] = item.Nombre;
            arr.push(objColumns);

            //objColumns = {};
            //objColumns['field'] = 'Valor';//NuevasColumnasAsoc[i].Valor;
            //objColumns['title'] = Espec_list.Nombre;
            //arr.push(objColumns);
        });

        return arr;
    }
```

lo que quiero hacer es, que 2 array se conviertan en 1, lo explico:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tanto en el segundo como en el tercero, se muestra el mismo array1, lo que quier hacer es colocarlo en una sola columna, que diga mas o menos lo dice el primero, que se haga columnas que digan lo siguiente: Id = 2, Nombre = Prueba Celeste, Peso = 85.
Agradezco la ayuda.

**Esta es la respuesta que obtengo actualmente.**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No termina de quedar claro qué es lo que quieres conseguir. ¿A qué te refieres con que los dos arrays se conviertan en uno? ¿Cómo relacionarías cada valor con la columna a la que pertenece?

Comment: Es que es es mi punto, como puedo lograr que no me haga 2 filas como se muestra la imagen 2. Lo que quiero lograr es que diga: Id:2, Nombre: Prueba Celeste, Peso:85. Esto último sólo se puede ver en una sola fila, no en dos como aparece actualmente.

Comment: No se entiende, intento entenderlo. Falta código, pero si quieres juntar dos array usa el método concat de la clase array

Comment: En alguna parte tienes especificado que `Espec_Id` 2 significa `nombre` y `Espec_Id` 6 significa `peso`? ¿Cuál es el contenido completo de `lstEspecificaciones`?

Comment: Además, qué esperarías poner en `lista2[4]`? Porque `lista.field` no significa nada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Supongamos que tienes un diccionario del tipo:

```
var diccionario= {
  2 : 'Nombre',
  6 : 'Peso'
};
```

El cual nos dice que el `Espec_Id` 2 indica el nombre y `Espec_Id` 6 indica el peso.

La variable lista viene siendo una lista de columnas, equivalente a declarar:

```
var columnas = [
    {field:"IdNew", title:"Id"},
    {field:"Nombre", title:"Nombre"},
    {field:"Peso", title:"Peso"}
];
```

en tu listado final quieres que el primer elemento sean las columnas, así que podrías poner

```
var listado = [columnas];
```

Después tienes una lista (que sería tu `lista2`) con elementos que representan atributos y valores de un mismo `IdNew`. Por ejemplo

```
var elementos = [
    {Espec_Id: 2, IdNew: 2, valor: 'Prueba 1'},
    {Espec_Id: 6, IdNew: 2, valor: '85'},
    {Espec_Id: 2, IdNew: 3, valor: 'Prueba 2'},
    {Espec_Id: 6, IdNew: 3, valor: '44'},
];
```

Para convertir ese listado en algo más utilizable (y ya que estás utilizando `underscore`), puedes usar el método `reduce`)

```
var lista_agrupada = _.reduce(lista2, function(acumulado, elemento) {
  acumulado[elemento.idNew] = acumulado[elemento.idNew] || {}; 
  acumulado[elemento.idNew]['idNew'] = elemento.idNew;

  // el significado de Espec_Id es tomado del diccionario
  var llave = diccionario[elemento.Espec_Id];
  acumulado[elemento.idNew][llave]=elemento.valor;
  return acumulado;
},{});
```

El terminar este bucle tendrías que `lista_agrupada` es un objeto:

```
{
    2:  {IdNew:2, Nombre: 'Prueba 1', Peso: '85' },
    3:  {IdNew:3, Nombre: 'Prueba 2', Peso: '44' },
}
```

Puedes iterar sobre ese objeto y añadir cada elemento a tu `listado`

```
_.each(lista_agrupada,function(elemento) {
    var fila = [];
    fila.push({field: 'idNew',  title: elemento.idNew});
    fila.push({field: 'Nombre',  title: elemento.Nombre});
    fila.push({field: 'Peso',  title: elemento.Peso});
    listado.push(fila);
});
```

Al final de lo cual `listado` tendría la forma

```
[
    [
        {field:"IdNew", title:"Id"},
        {field:"Nombre", title:"Nombre"},
        {field:"Peso", title:"Peso"}
    ],
    [
        {field:"IdNew", title:"2"},
        {field:"Nombre", title:"Prueba 1"},
        {field:"Peso", title:"85"}
    ],
    [
        {field:"IdNew", title:"3"},
        {field:"Nombre", title:"Prueba 2"},
        {field:"Peso", title:"44"}
    ]
]
```

Debo decir que casi todo esto lo hice adivinando qué querías decir con tu pregunta, y que tu estructura de datos está realmente muy desordenada.

Comment: Gracias hombre... Me funcionó perfectamente...